# Routing AVSpeechSynthesizer to AU Host in iOS

Tags: audio, ios7, audiounit, avspeechsynthesizer

Is it possible to grab/save/route the output of the AVSpeechSynthesizer so that it can be manipulated as audio so I can run audio processing on the audio (kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2 ) and then play it?